# Is there existing terminology/notation for the distance to the set $2r\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, metric-spaces, modular-arithmetic, terminology

For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, define
$$|x|_{r}^{\mathrm{mod}} = d(x,2r\mathbb{Z}),$$ by which I mean the minimum distance from $x$ to an element of the set $2r\mathbb{Z} = \{2rn : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}.$

> **Questions.** Does this function have a special name?
>
> Are there any notations already in use for it?

*Motivation.*

I think that the function of interest shows up in the context of the inverse trigonometric functions. In particular, it seems to be the case that for all $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, we have:

$$\cos^{-1}(\cos \theta) = |\theta|_\pi^{\mathrm{mod}}$$

This means, for example, that the angle (in the sense of inner product spaces) between the vectors $$(\cos \theta,\sin\theta) \qquad (\cos \varphi,\sin\varphi)$$ is given by $|\theta-\varphi|^{\mathrm{mod}}_\pi$.

*Further Observations.*

For all real number $x$ it holds that $|x|_r^{\mathrm{mod}} \in [0,r].$

In general, the function $$\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ $$x \mapsto |x|^\mathrm{mod}_r$$ looks like $x \mapsto |x|$ on the interval $[-r,r]$, and then changes direction. Ultimately, it looks like a triangle wave that's been shifted upward so that it's value is positive for every $x$. It's gradient is always either $1$ or $-1$, except at the points where the gradient is undefined.

If I'm not mistaken, it can be explicitly computed as $$|x|_r^{\mathrm{mod}} = \mathrm{min}(|x \,\mathbin{\mathrm{mod}}\, 2r|,|-\!x\,\mathbin{\mathrm{mod}}\, 2r|),$$ where $x\,\mathbin{\mathrm{mod}}\, q$ is defined as the unique $y \in [0,q)$ such that $x-y \in q\mathbb{Z}$.

Furthermore, the function $d^{\mathrm{mod}}_r : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ given by $$d^{\mathrm{mod}}_r(x,y) = |y-x|_r^{\mathrm{mod}}$$ should be a pseudometric; in particular, it should be the pseudometric obtained by precomposing the metric on $\mathbb{R}/\!\!\!\sim$ with the projection $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}/\!\!\sim$, where equivalence of real numbers is defined as follows: $$x \sim y = x-y \in 2r\mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a specific notation, but the nearest multiple of $2r$ is $2r$ times the nearest integer of $\dfrac x{2r}$, the  `nint` function for English-speakers. Not sure they're official, but two notations I've seen  for the nearest integer  are 
$$\lbrack x\rbrack\quad\text{and}\quad \{x\},$$
so you might denote it, say $$\;\color{red}{\Biggl\lvert x-2r\left\lbrack \dfrac x{2r}\right\rbrack\Biggr \rvert}\quad\text{ or }\quad\color{blue}{\Biggl\lvert x-2r\left\{ \dfrac x{2r}\right\}\Biggr\rvert}.
$$
or even introduce notations line $\lbrack x\rbrack_r$ or $\{x\}_r$ for this nearest multiple of $2r$ and write
$$\color{red}{\Bigl\lvert x-[x]_r\Bigr\rvert}\quad\text{ or }\quad\color{blue}{\Bigl\lvert x-\{x\}_r\Bigr\rvert}$$

Note that in terms of modular arithmetic,  this is simply $\;x\bmod 2r$ if the latter is $<r$, $2r-x\bmod2r\;$ if it $\ge r$.

Comment: (+1), but shouldn't that be $2r$ times the nearest integer of $x/(2r)$...? (Scale the number line by $1/(2r)$, measure distance, rescale to original units.)

Comment: Oh! yes, of course. I'll fix the answer. Thanks for pointing the error!

Comment: I don't get it. The nearest integer to $4.2$ for example is $4$. But $|4.2|_1^{\mathrm{mod}}=0.2.$ Perhaps you meant "distance to the nearest integer?" If so, I don't think this is a very good implementation. The integers fail to be a Chebyshev set, so properly speaking "nearest integer" doesn't specify a function. Of course, in practice we can get around this by choosing a convention - always round toward $0$, for example - but it's a bit artificial. Better to just deal with the distance directly, rather than trying to project onto the set imo.

Comment: @goblin: You're right, I misunderstood your question. I've modified my answer.

Comment: But what about my point that this is a bad implementation? [Here's a brief discussion about Chebyshev sets.](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Chebyshev_set) I think that, if we want to use rounding to an integer to implement the desired function, the formula $$|x|_r = \mathrm{min}(x-\mathrm{floor}_{2r}(x),\mathrm{ciel}_{2r}(x)-x)$$ is probably a better way to do it, since $\mathrm{floor}_q$ and $\mathrm{ciel}_q$ are left and right adjoints to the inclusion $q\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and hence non-arbitrary.

Comment: I don't see a real difference, but I'm no specialist of Chebyshev sets. B.t.w. where is the `ciel` function defined? I only know the `ceil` function.